# Unable to install selenium using pip

Tags: python

I am trying to install selinium using pip in windows 10. Even when pip is up to date, it is throwing the same error: `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement selinium`. I'm trying to install it like this:

```
pip install selinium 
pip3 install selinium
```

Comment: Basic troubleshooting should have been done

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you misspelled the module, it is called `selenium` not `selinium`, so you can use:

```
pip install selenium
pip3 install selenium
```

You always should read the docs install page, the install page of the docs of selenium is the below:

> https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html

Answer (score 1):

That's because it's *selenium*.